# comparing two inputs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i just began a project in html and jquery and i have to compare validate a period.it means that user must enter two years and the second one should be bigger than the second one.i tried this and it doesn't work:
this is my html code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="pe">Période de fréquentation </label>  
  <div class="col-md-2">

  De <input id="pe" name="pe" type="text" placeholder="année" class="form-control input-md">
  à <input id="pe2" name="pe2" type="text" placeholder="année" class="form-control input-md"> 
  </div>
</div><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

and this one is my jquery function:

```js
 ` $(document).ready(function() {
$('#pe').click(function() { {
    if ($(this) > $('#pe')){
  alert("veuillez corriger la periode de frequentation");
  return false ;
}
else return true;
}}}`
```

Comment: "the **second** one should be bigger than the **second** one". Please rephrase.

Comment: i mean that if you put 2000 in the first form and 1999 in the second,the function should return false.And 1999 in the first and 2000 in the second one returns true

Comment: you are comparing two selections to each other. not two primitive values. THat is you are comparing the references of two objects. Which is larger hardly ever makes sense in that context

Comment: @user3430205 I noticed you ticked my answer as correct but then unticked it. Did the solution not work?

Comment: sorry,i misticked it without knowing and yeah it worked ,thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wanted to check if `#pe` is larger than `#pe2`

```
$('#pe').click(function() { {
if ($(this).val() > $('#pe2').val()){
    alert("veuillez corriger la periode de frequentation");
    return false ;
}
else return true;
```